# Are these two RAM chips compatible together?

Tags: memory, speed, compatibility

I have

```
Kigston KVR1333D3N9/2G
```

in the motherboard already. I wish to add

```
G Skill [ Ripjaws ] F3-10666CL9S-4GBRL (4Gx1)
```

Question is, will these two chips work together? Please guys, I need help.

These are Motherboard Specs:

[image: CPU]
[image: SPD]
[image: Memory]
[image: Mainboard]

Manufacturer spec pages: [Kigston ram specs](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/kvr1333d3n9_2g.pdf) and [G Skill ram specs](https://www.gskill.com/en/product/f3-10666cl9s-4gbrl)

Comment: The "motherboard specs" are actually screenshots of the CPU-Z application. They provide no information about the motherboard. Try the Mainboard tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both chips are DDR3 so the answer is yes. The one you wish to add is slower than the one currently installed. This will make both chips run at the speed of the slowest, which is less than optimal. The only thing left to check is whether the motherboard supports chips of 4GB capacity. Consult the manual of the motherboard for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
i uploaded the mainboard tab little while ago.
Manual says max is 4gb. So will those work with no harm and with good performence?

Comment: Ow - Si - Да - Ja - Yes